# Full-width slideshow, having issues accurately getting viewport dimensions

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, viewport

I'm creating a simple image/content slideshow. The slideshow needs to have position fixed or absolute, with relatively-positioned content below it (so the content will cover the slideshow on scroll). I've got it working fairly well without the content. But when I add the content, I encounter two issues:

1. I am unable to set the top margin with JS
2. On browser resize, the height of the viewport is calculated incorrectly such that the resulting dimension is more than that of the actual viewport. This causes the slideshow to get taller ... and taller, when I would like it to remain 200px shorter than the viewport.

Here's what I'm using to get dimensions:

```
// The amount of content to preview below the slideshow, above the fold
previewContent = 100;
slideCount = $('#slides li').length;
slideWidth = $(window).width();
slideHeight = $(window).height() - previewContent;
slideWindowUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
```

... and to set them:

```
// Set the width & height of each slide
$('#slides li, #slideWindow').css({width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

// Set the width of the slide container (<ul>)
$('#slides').css({ width: slideWindowUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
```

I've created a JSFiddle with the full implementation, content commented out:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wg5V8/5/

Any help would be great. I'm sure it's simple ... I'm just quite stuck.